# asp.net client side validator on div with pop up

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side, validation, client-side-scripting

I have the following snippet from a project I recently hopped on to.

```
<div id="divDescEn" href="editor.aspx?field=1" class="textarea popup" runat="server">
</div>
```

The above snippet is a popup form with a rich text editor on it. Once the save button is pressed on the popup form, the text is then placed on the form in the RTE "placeholder"

I am trying to include the div as part of my validation summary with other controls on the form that use asp.net Validators.

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

Thanks
TR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DIV's don't naturally support validation.  What you could do to work around that is use a `CustomValidator`, set the `ClientValidationFunction` to a function that checks the inner contents for any text.  On the server, using `ServerValidate`, you can check that the DIV has some inner content that isn't blank, as long as the contents are posted back successfully.

Comment: Thanks @Brian-Mains

`function custdivDescEnClientValidate(sender, args) {
var text = document.getElementById("divDescEn").innerHTML;
if (text== '')
{
args.IsValid = false;  
   }` 
This then plugged in nicely to the rest of the client side validation I had in place.